# Не работает код по смене цветов текста в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, rgb

Пытаюсь реализовать функцию, которая постепенно, с небольшим интервалом меняет цвет текста.

[image: Цвет меняется, как показано на картинке по полузунку]
В ХТМЛ только айди "test" с текстом, а вот в JS:

```js
var p = document.getElementById('text');
window.setInterval(changeColors, 500);  //cмена цвета на 15 каждые полсекунды

var colors = [255, 0, 0]

function changeColors(colors) {
  if (colors[0] == 255 && colors[1] != 255 && colors[2] == 0) {
    colors[1] += 15;
    let colorsToString = colors.join();
    return p.style.color = "rgb(" + colorsToString + ")"
  } else if (colors[0] != 0 && colors[1] == 255 && colors[2] == 0) {
    colors[0] -= 15;
    let colorsToString = colors.join();
    return p.style.color = "rgb(" + colorsToString + ")"
  } else if (colors[0] == 0 && colors[1] == 255 && colors[2] != 255) {
    colors[2] += 15;
    let colorsToString = colors.join();
    return p.style.color = "rgb(" + colorsToString + ")"
  } else if (colors[0] == 0 && colors[1] != 0 && colors[2] == 255) {
    colors[1] -= 15;
    let colorsToString = colors.join();
    return p.style.color = "rgb(" + colorsToString + ")"
  } else if (colors[0] != 255 && colors[1] == 0 && colors[2] == 255) {
    colors[0] += 15;
    let colorsToString = colors.join();
    return p.style.color = "rgb(" + colorsToString + ")"
  } else if (colors[0] == 255 && colors[1] == 0 && colors[2] != 0) {
    colors[2] -= 15;
    let colorsToString = colors.join();
    return p.style.color = "rgb(" + colorsToString + ")"
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Javascript</p>
```

Comment: вас не смущает код `let ...; return ...` который повторяется N раз ?

Comment: return нет, ведь если if верный, то код выполнится, а если нет, то он начнет проверять следующий.
let смущает самого, но ничего лучше придумать не смог.

Comment: в данном случае как в математике, общий множитель можно вынести за скобки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

Цвет задавать удобно в шкале `hsl`, меняя только первый компонент по кругу 0-360

```js
var i = 0, p = document.getElementById('text');
setInterval(e => p.style.color = `hsl(${++i%360},55%,55%)`, 50);
```

```html
<span id="text" style="font-size:100px">example text<span>
```

Comment: Лично меня всегда смущают переменные вроде `i` в вашем примере, которые со временем потенциально могут "переполниться"

Comment: @smellyshovel в примере из 2х строчек нет смысла тратить время на семантику переменных

Comment: Тоже верно, но в комментариях пускай останется висеть, мало ли что.

Comment: @smellyshovel а вообще это вкусовщина, попишите на glsl тоже полюбите переменные из 1-2 символов

Comment: Это вы о чем сейчас? Я, если что, имел в виду, что пусть лучше информация о потенциальном баге останется в комментарии (на всякий случай), а о чем Вы, я не понял.

Comment: @smellyshovel господи, вы про переполнение дабла?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а про что можно было подумать, кроме переполнения типа? :)

Comment: @teran хз как я так понял в первый раз, но я подумал о длине имени переменной

Comment: Я про то, что если очень долго и усердно прибавлять единичку к нолику, то рано или поздно нолик превратится в Infinity, с которым явно будут проблемы :) Да ладно, развели демагогию тут

Comment: Кстати, что еще может быть интересно. `% 360` вообще можно убрать, без него будет тот же эффект, что и с ним. Но это ни в коем случае не наезд, просто подумал, что может быть интересно

Comment: @smellyshovel справедливое замечание, я понимаю что угол он и есть угол, однако тут чтобы не нарушать понимание работы шкалы hsl я решил привести аргумент в диапазон первого оборота

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал об этом способе. 
Не подскажете,а откуда у нас появилась переменная i и как потом JS понимает, что это цифра?

Comment: @ДмитрийКузнецов внимательно смотрите в начало 1 строки

Comment: Точно, совсем глаза замылил, спасибо!

Comment: @smellyshovel я не поленился, получается что если бы таймер срабатывал не раз в 50 мс а раз в одну, ждать бы пришлось примерно 285 тысяч лет

Comment: @ДмитрийКузнецов Всегда пожалуйста, так же из hsl удобнее получать случайный цвет и не получать темные оттенки или наоборот светлые

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я тоже не поленился, и мои расчеты отличаются от ваших всего на 1.34% :D Сойдемся же на том, что в данной ситуации действительно без разницы, но в целом подобные вещи имеет смысл иметь в виду

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка вашего кода в том, что вы определяете `colors` сначала как переменную, а потом как параметр функции. Естественно при вызове функции через `setInterval` никакой параметр туда не передается, и параметр принимает значение `undefined`, тем самым перекрывая значение объявленной переменной.

```js
var p = document.getElementById('text');
window.setInterval(changeColors, 500);  //cмена цвета на 15 каждые полсекунды

var colors = { r:255, g:0, b:0 };

function changeColors() {
  var c = colors;
  
  if (     c.r == 255 && c.g != 255 && c.b == 0)   c.g += 15;    
  else if (c.r != 0   && c.g == 255 && c.b == 0)   c.r -= 15;
  else if (c.r == 0   && c.g == 255 && c.b != 255) c.b += 15;
  else if (c.r == 0   && c.g != 0   && c.b == 255) c.g -= 15;
  else if (c.r != 255 && c.g == 0   && c.b == 255) c.r += 15;
  else if (c.r == 255 && c.g == 0   && c.b != 0)   c.b -= 15;    
    
  p.style.color = `rgb(${c.r}, ${c.g}, ${c.b})`;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Javascript</p>
```

Comment: плюсик Вам за разбор полетов

Comment: Спасибо большое за разбор, понял

Answer (score 0):

Для меня осталось под вопросом, для чего if-else, если вам заранее известны все нужные цвета) Поэтому предложу еще такой вариант:

```js
var x = document.getElementById('text1');
var y = document.getElementById('text2');

Rainbowing(x);
Rainbowing(y);

var rainbow = [
  '255,0,0',   // Красный
  '255,125,0', // Оранжевский
  '220,220,0', // Желтый
  '0,240,0',   // Зеленый
  '0,240,240', // Голбуой
  '0,0,240',   // Синий
  '240,0,240'  // Филалетовский
];

function Rainbowing(el){
  var index = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    el.style.color = 'rgb(' + rainbow[index] + ')';
    index = (index == rainbow.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.rainbow { transition: 3s; color: red;}
```

```html
<p id="text1" class="rainbow">Javascript</p>
<p id="text2" class="rainbow">Ацетилсалициловая кислота</p>
```

`transition` делает всю плавную магию))

Comment: Потому что я хотел сделать плавный перебор цветов. К тому же, я даже не был уверен, что шаг 15 нормальный, возможно, его надо было уменьшить.
Спасибо.